# Align divs wth different height on top

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML markup:

```
<div class="awards-wrap">
    <div class="award">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum 2013</p>
    </div>
    <div class="award">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
    <div class="award">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum 2013</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my css:

```
.awards-wrap {
    background: gray;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.award {
    max-width: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

So they're all aligned now in center and is also responsive, but I want the images to all be aligned on top.

I've tried to do it this way:

```
.awards-wrap {
    background: gray;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
}

.award {
    max-width: 250px;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

But it removes the responsiveness and being aligned on the center. I know I can use media queries for it and all but I would like to do it simply like its behavior on `inline-block`.

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gnhpfgu4/1/) for it

Comment: Try `display: flex;`.

Comment: Same as table-cell the divs doesn't align on the center anymore and is not responsive as well.

Comment: Add `flex-wrap: wrap`. Please see sebastianbrosch's answer. :)

Comment: Yup, that's what's missing. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find a solution with flexbox:

```css
.awards-wrap {
  background:gray;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:center;
  text-align:center;
}
.award {
  max-width:250px;
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="awards-wrap">
  <div class="award">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum 2013</p>
  </div>
  <div class="award">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="award">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum 2013</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Explanation:**
With this solution all images are at top of the box. But with with `display:flex;` you have additional to set a space between the boxes. With `flex-wrap:wrap;` the solution works responsive too!

I cleaned up the CSS to a minimal solution.

Comment: I see. That explains it, I've looked into the `flex` display and thought it should've been doing what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `vertical-align` property for this and set it to `top`. It will align the divs to top and center as well. Here is the updated CSS:

```
.award {
 max-width: 250px;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align:top;
}
```

Here is a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gnhpfgu4/4/) to the updated JSFiddle

Comment: This is actually a simpler solution, thank you! Not so sure what to use now between the two :/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: flex` for that matter. Just add this rules to your wrapper:

```
display: flex;
align-items: flex-start;
```

Try it below:

```css
.awards-wrap {
  background: gray;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.award {
  max-width: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="awards-wrap">
  <div class="award">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum 2013</p>
  </div>
  <div class="award">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="award">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum 2013</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Same as `table-cell` the divs doesn't align on the center anymore and is not responsive as well.

Answer (score 1):

why do you want to use `display: inline-block` ?
Does the following help?

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.awards-wrap {
  /* other styles */
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.award {
  /* other styles */
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamster/gnhpfgu4/3/)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include in the question that I also need all the divs to be center aligned

Answer (score 1):

use in style

```
.award
{
vertical-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have modified the code and all the images are now position at the top.

HTML code

```
<div class="awards-wrap">
    <div id="award">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum 2013</p>
    </div>
    <div id="award2">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
    <div id="award3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum 2013</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS file

```
.awards-wrap 
{
    background: gray;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#award 
{
    max-width: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 34px;
}

#award2 
{
    max-width: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 102px;
}

#award3 
{
    max-width: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```